# Keyboard Layout QWERTTY or QWERTZ

Tags: keyboard, layout

I notice that the Dell website only offers their 3000 series Inspiron desktops with a QWERTZ keyboard (i.e. QWERTY costs extra !). On querying this, Dell tell me that (quote) "QWERTZ is the normal layout in UK. QWERTY is International".
Wow ! Have I been living in a time warp ?
Is QWERTY no longer the UK standard ?

Answer (score 1):

What rubbish!

From WikiPedia:

> The QWERTZ or QWERTZU keyboard is a widely used computer and
>   typewriter keyboard layout that is mostly used in Central Europe. The
>   name comes from the first six letters at the top left of the keyboard:
>   Q, W, E, R, T, and Z.

UK Keyboards are QWERTY always. the only difference is where the £ and # keys are and maybe a € symbol and a couple of others. But the main keys are the same for UK and US layouts.

Comment: And notably the @ key's in the second row, rather than the top IIRC. That's a critical thing

Comment: Yes, sorry, got bored trying to remember the other keys :}

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. QWERTY is the **International** standard.

To Quote:

> The QWERTZ layout is fairly widely used in Germany, Austria,
>   Switzerland and much of Central Europe. The main difference between it
>   and QWERTY is that Y and Z are swapped, and some special characters
>   such as brackets are replaced by the diacritical characters Ä, Ö, Ü
>   and ß.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#QWERTZ)